# UITableView with read more button after the 120 character in the UILabel in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have one tableview and inside on UILabel, 120 characters have to show there and after read more button, when we clicking on read more button cell want to expand as per the content of UILabel text. please help me to do this.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
if(isReadMoreButtonTouched && [indexPath row]== indexOfReadMoreButton)

{
    NSLog(@"cccccccccccccccccccccc -------- %f",size.height);
    return size.height+52;;
}
else{
    return 120.0f;
}
}
```

here the size is the height of UILabel

```
- (CGFloat)getLabelHeight:(UILabel*)label
{
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
CGSize size;

NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
CGSize boundingBox = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}
                                              context:context].size;

size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));

return size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to substring label's string to 120 first and then assigning that 120 substring chars to label. When you tap more button, assign the full original length string to the label again, it will automatically grow cell height if you're using builtin dynamic height of cell for row. 
Meanwhile you can also check this [CollapsibleLabel](https://github.com/hilalbaig/CollapsibleLabel/blob/master/CollapsibleLabel/CollapsibleLabel.swift).